# How to customize the return output of Ruby commands in Pry

Tags: ruby, irb, read-eval-print-loop, pry

I was able to customize the prompt for Pry with the `Pry.config.prompt` setting in ~/.pryrc in order to make Pry simpler for kids.  Now I want to get rid of the return output:

```
Enter Ruby code> puts 'hello'
hello
=> nil
Enter Ruby code>
```

The `=> nil` is confusing for a kid just learning to program.  Can I suppress the return value output in Pry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. Either add `;` to the end of each line or replace the default `Pry.config.print` with a `proc` of your own. For example, adding something like

```
Pry.config.print = Proc.new { |output, value| }
```

to your `~/.pryrc` should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect!!  And actually I realized I do want the return value to be displayed if it's not nil...  so I added this to `~/.pryrc`: `Pry.config.print = Proc.new { |output, value| output.puts "=> #{value.inspect}" unless value == nil }`